# How to do a public site with sharePoint on premise

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-2013

I have to build a faccing public site with his own visual identity with sharepoint 'on premise', have someone know some tutorial or online class about how to do this. Because didn't find anything clear about how to do this with sharepoint in my researches

Comment: Narrow your question, do you want to make your site anonymous?  how to customize your sharepoint look and feel? Seems like you don't have a clue about Sharepoint in the broad sense, google for tutorials first (http://andreasglaser.com/learn-sharepoint)

Comment: Thanks for the comment man, I'll look at the link.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not an SharePoint expert, I believe what you are asking is a loaded question that encompasses several topics of knowledge and technical hurdles you would have to learn or overcome. There are a lot of details missing from your request, so I can only offer you some topics you will need to be familiar with as I have not seen any single tutorial that shows what you are asking for. But you should be able to find tutorials on individual topics that would be relevant to your request:

**Public Facing Site**

- Opening your on-premise SharePoint server to the public can be done by changing network settings which is a straight forward task for any network admin.
- Best to use a domain (ex mysite.com). If you don't have one, you can purchase a domain. Then have it registered and configured to connect with your server(s),
- Some other things to consider is security, firewalls, load balancing, DMZ zones and business policies.

**Own Visual Identity (a custom look of SharePoint)**

- One method is to create a custom master page for SharePoint which can be done via Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer.  This requires knowledge on web development such as CSS, HTML and possibly javascript. Developing a on-premise SharePoint environment with Visual Studio requires a lot (i mean alot) of setup and work.
- Another method is to use the SharePoint theming engine to create custom themes.
- You can also buy pre-built themes from other sources.

**Final thoughts**

- Unless absolutely required, I would avoid using a on-premise SharePoint to host a public site as there are much more simpler and cost effective solutions out there. There is also SharePoint online which will probably provide most of what you need out of the box.  Need to ask yourself what this public facing site will do and if SharePoint is the right product to use as I consider SharePoint complex and suited for specific needs. I worked with a on-premise SharePoint solution and it takes a crew of IT professionals and tons of money for maintenance and development.